# Automatically sign in to msonline and azuread Modules - possible?

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, azure-active-directory, provisioning

I would like to be able to provision apps through AzureAD by way of assigning an AD Security Group to it. Unfortunately, we don't have a P1 or P2 license, meaning that the only way to make this happen is to add users individually through the AzureAD portal.

I can accomplish this task with Powershell sure, but this still requires the manual process of authenticating with msonline and azuread to use the modules. Is there a way for me to be able to automatically connect to azuread and msonline, so that I can place this script in a task manager to run automatically?

If I can just get that part done, then I can create a script where a for-loop would iterate through the users in the security group to then add/remove users from the AzureAD app, hence provisioning and deprovisioning users.

I hope this description makes sense and I thank you all for the time you too to read this.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, we can use the following script to connect

```
#Msonline
$name = "your user account"
$password = "your "
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)

Connect-MsolService -Credential $mycreds
Get-MsolAccountSku
```

[image]

```
#AzureAD
$name = "your user account"
$password = "your "
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $mycreds
Get-AzureADDirectoryRole
```

[image]

Comment: Storing password in plain text in scripts is a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Is there a way to do this without having the password showing in plain text?

Comment: @JSRendar Regarding the issue, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552071/connect-to-azure-ad-from-powershell-without-prompt